# What is the best terminology to use on a modal's buttons when a user is about to leave said page?

Tags: terminology, modal, administration

I hope this question is not too banal. I would like to use the best terminology for a modal's buttons.

Context: 
I'm building a feature for an administrative tool. The feature is on a customer profile's dashboard which contains items that link to other administrative tools ultimately sending the admin outside of the customer's profile. (Changes are saved every time an Admin makes a change so there's no risk to lose progress)

When the Admin clicks on the item, a modal pops up and says 
"You're about to leave this profile to x page. Are you sure you want to leave?"

Option for buttons
`Stay on Page` `Continue`
| `Cancel` `Continue`
| `Cancel` `yes`

Is there one in particular that is more commonly used?
thank you for your time.

Comment: If there's no risk of data loss, why are you putting a dialog in their way?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The admin management tool we have contains multiple products. The feature I’m building for a customer’s dashboard  includes shortcuts to other tools (products) like volunteering, education, events, etc…. which don’t exist under the customer’s profile. Because the admin would leave that product to an other I felt the need for a modal. But I agree with you I am creating more roadblocks. This is also a temporary solution to a product that needs an overall rebuild. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: thanks for the clarity. In that case, see the articles and examples I've referenced below to make clear button labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would want to use `Stay on Profile`and Continue`. Cancel makes it sound like the navigation is more serious than it is. You have all the data stored, it sounds like you just want to flag a context switch in the application.

I would avoid confusing page and profile though. I'm not sure how much room you have to maneuver but it's best to keep the terminology consistent.

Comment: I will definitely keep this in mind. Profile would be a more consistent term in this context. Thank you grmdgs!

Answer (score 1):

## If there's no risk of data loss, ideally you don't put a dialog in the way of the admin.

From what it sounds like, the admin doesn't risk anything by going to another tools page. Confirmation dialogs are normally used for:

- Warning of data loss
- Confirmation of a destructive action
- A process that can complete an action without the user having to navigate to another page.

#### Is the concern that the admin will need to keep the profile accessible?

If the admin expects to keep the main profile pages readily accessible, you could open the other tools in another tab.

[image]

There are certain user roles, like DevOps, Security Admins, and others where tabbing between multiple windows is necessary, and allows them to maintain multiple timely contexts without having to search through browser history.

## If you need a dialog, make the buttons clear.

**[Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#alert-dialog)** has some guidelines on button labels:

> Don’t use action text that fails to indicate what the selection will do. “Cancel” and “Delete” better indicate what will occur in this dialog.

[image]

[image]

There another thoughtful article, **[Primary and Secondary Action Buttons](https://uxplanet.org/primary-secondary-action-buttons-c16df9b36150)**

> It’s often better to name a button to explain what it does than to use a generic label (like “OK”).
>
> Use a verb whenever possible instead of ‘Yes’ or ‘OK’ because your buttons will make sense out of context with the explanatory text or title.

Comment: Thank you Mike, These examples and your knowledge is appreciated!